# Python MySQL Cursor being blocked by read-only priviledges

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I've been using the Python MySQL Database MySQL connection (mysql-connector=2.2.9 and mysql=0.0.3) for almost a year and it worked as a charm.

However, our WRITE permissions were removed from a core database. So far, it should not be a problem, because we only fetch data from that database and write to other databases where we have the permissions.

However, since the cursor interface does not provide another way of fetching data other than `cursor.execute(query)`, It seems that MySQL cannot guarantee that the currently executed query is a read-only command. Therefore, I get the error below

```
"Access denied for user 'myuser'@'10.64.XXX.XX' (using password: YES)]
```

The relevant code is below

```
def get_connection(database, username, password):
        return MySQLDatabase(host=getenv(DATABASE_HOST), port=getenv(DATABASE_PORT),
                             database=database,
                             user=username, password=password).connection


self.read_connection = self.get_connection(database, usr, pwd)
cursor_read = self.read_connection.cursor()
cursor_write = self.write_connection.cursor()

operative_function_query = """SELECT * FROM operative_function"""

cursor_read.execute(operative_function_query) #this line fails
results = cursor_read.fetchall()
```

- Trying the same query in another DB with write permissions does not
  fail
- I am able to run SELECT statements directly in the database using the
  same username/password

Anyone has faced this issue before? Is there a workaround to fetch data from a database with read-only privileges (I expected to find a SELECT method in the interface, but there isn't one).

Perhaps another python package out there?

Comment: Are you able to execute this very query in the database with this user? If the function called requires write permissions, it's not a Python issue.

Comment: Yeah – try running the same query from a MySQL shell, and when it doesn't work, talk with your database administrator.

Comment: Privileges are checked by the server, not the client. If you have SELECT privilege, then you should be able to run that statement. I suspect you don't even have SELECT privilege (maybe you only have USAGE privilege, which means you can connect but nothing else). You can confirm your user's privileges by running `SHOW GRANTS` when you are connected as the same MySQL user.

Comment: You were all right. Indeed it was a mistake on my side providing invalid credentials. The read privileges I had were sufficient to connect to the DB using pymysql cursor